# Php get data with api key

Tags: php, api

I want to make a PHP page for sending like with API from social media panel which I have a membership.

They give me this example but I don't understand completely.

Example Code:

```
<?php
   class Api
   {
      public $api_url = 'http://domain/api/v2'; // API URL

      public $api_key = ''; // Your API key

      public function order($data) { // add order
        $post = array_merge(array('key' => $this->api_key, 'action' => 'add'), $data);
        return json_decode($this->connect($post));
      }

      public function status($order_id) { // get order status
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
          'key' => $this->api_key,
          'action' => 'status',
          'id' => $order_id
        )));
      }

      public function services() { // get services
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
          'key' => $this->api_key,
          'action' => 'services',
        )));
      }

      public function balance() { // get balance
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
          'key' => $this->api_key,
          'action' => 'balance',
        )));
      }


      private function connect($post) {
        $_post = Array();
        if (is_array($post)) {
          foreach ($post as $name => $value) {
            $_post[] = $name.'='.urlencode($value);
          }
        }
        $ch = curl_init($this->api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        if (is_array($post)) {
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, join('&', $_post));
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0 && empty($result)) {
          $result = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
      }
   }

   // Examples

   $api = new Api();

   $services = $api->services(); # return all services

   $balance = $api->balance(); # return user balance

   // add order

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 1, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 100)); # Default

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 1, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 100, 'keywords'=>"test, testing")); # SEO

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 1, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'comments' => "good pic\ngreat photo\n:)\n;)")); # Custom Comments

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 4, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 100, 'usernames'=>"test, testing", 'hashtags'=>"#goodphoto")); # Mentions with Hashtags

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 5, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'usernames' => "test\nexample\nfb")); # Mentions Custom List

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 6, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 100, 'hashtag'=>"test")); # Mentions Hashtag

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 7, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 1000, 'username'=>"test")); # Mentions User Followers

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 8, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 1000, 'media'=>"http://example.com/p/Ds2kfEr24Dr")); # Mentions Media Likers

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 9, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 1000, 'usernames'=>"test")); # Mentions

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 10, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test')); # Package

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 12, 'link' => 'http://example.com/test', 'quantity' => 100, 'runs' => 10, 'interval' => 60)); # Drip-feed

   $order = $api->order(array('service' => 11, 'username' => 'username', 'min' => 100, 'max' => 110, 'posts' => 0,'delay' => 30)); # Subscriptions

   $status = $api->status($order->order); # return status, charge, remains, start count

?>
```

For now, I want to see "get balance" on my PHP page but I couldn't do. I fill API URL and API key. Could you help me how can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Voting down because it is too broad and primarily opinion based - you could research this and oAuth 2.0

Comment: SO is a Q&A where we can help you if you run into some _specific_ issue with your _existing_ code, but we're not here to write it for you. The cde you linked to (which should been included in the actual question) is simply a class. Since this is pretty much PHP 101, I would recommend looking into some getting started tutorials about PHP and OOP since you will definitely run into more questions pretty soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the API by calling `balance()` on it, like so;

```php
$api = new Api();

$response = $api->balance();

// The response has "balance" and "currency" properties, which can be accessed like so;
echo "Your balance is " . $response->balance . " " . $response->currency;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i get this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string on line 71"

Comment: @Can1 - In which file does that error occur? I can't see any "object to string"-conversion in line 71 of the code you're showing.

Comment: I add @jack wilsdon code at the end of the page and that codes give that error. Now i tried as  "print_r($balance)", instead of "echo $balance" and i get these "stdClass Object ( [balance] => 0.45912 [currency] => USD )" How can i get only balance part?

Comment: @Can1 - Of course. The methods returns objects. Do: `$data = $api->balance();` and to echo it out, you should also check to see that you got a valid response: `echo isset($data->balance) ? $data->balance : 'Invalid response';`.

Comment: Added code explaining how to access the properties on the returned object.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i can get balance but couldn't get order status. Could you help me? $status = $api->status($order->order);

Comment: You need to pass in the order ID, not the order itself. Try `$order->id`.

Comment: @JackWilsdon     I tried this code but not work :(  `$order = $api->status(array('order' => '11111')); $add = $order->id;`